# How To Create Search Engine with Xapian

Tags: php, mysql, database, search-engine, xapian

I am trying create a search engine using Xapian on shared hosting, but I am not getting any idea where to start, I have downloaded the source file.

Xapian-core-1.2.12, 
Xapian-bindings-1.2.12 and 
Xapian-omega-1.2.12.

Now what to do with these source file, where to put it and how to install it i cant understand at thing from [this](http://xapian.org/docs/install.html) installation tutorial.

I am stuck at the initial steps of installation. I want to build it in PHP as i don't know Python.

I goggled a lot and searched here too but didn't find any clear explanation on how to build search with Xapian from scratch.

I shall be able to follow [this](http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/searching-with-xapian-and-php/index.html) tutorial after installing Xapian.

Please suggest any good tutorial or way to install Xapian on shared server.

Comment: is it possible to install it on the shared hosting . like sphinx is it require to start the service on the os ?

Comment: In installation guide they have explained like this..
If you don't have root access to install Xapian, you can specify a prefix in your home directory, for example:

./configure --prefix=/home/jenny/xapian-install

Comment: Who's your shared hosting provider for starters. Its highly unlikely a provider supplying a shared system will allow any form of change to the configuration of the box in any way shape form or another to ensure the security of all the clients on said machine. With that its possible you may have to take your hosting up a notch to something like VPS and even then thats ify as VPS is very similar to shared but your getting a virtual instance of a dedicated box. myhosting.com has cheap solutions that are pretty good, but thats a side point.

Comment: its also possible that even if you are able to bypass some needs for config changes that you may run into dependancies of the script your trying to run not being installed, enabled, or something to the effect there of. Shared systems are pretty locked down all in all.

Comment: @chris, i am on hostgator and you are right they don't have zlib, FreeBSD and zlib development installed which is prerequisites, so i guess i may not be able to use it on shared hosting.

Comment: Yea, hostgator is pretty strict like that, even with there VPS and Dedicated solutions, my suggestion is come to the company I use, they are cheap and you get a lot for your moneys worth. I have a VPS through them, its not a dedicated solution, but I have had those before as well. And this is the first VPS Ive used thats almost equal to the dedicated needs. I pay like $36 a month for my needs, and they have slightly cheaper.

Comment: In other words the dependancies you need will be accessable, I recently installed SugarCRM for one of my clients on my VPS which has a slue of dependancies of which I was able to either install or enable myself and then get everything up and running

Comment: iweb is also another good company but more expensive, worth it though.. since your starting a search engine, do try to keep in mind thats something that will need expansion sooner or later. depending on how well liked it gets. But if its a hit, your looking at many servers clustered together for one cause, future proofing though is always a good thing to bare in mind, last thing you want is to have services fail, when your boxed into a solution and will end up having a hard time getting out into a new one, not impossible but less headache in the future

Comment: Changing host and upgrading to vps or dedicated is the ultimate solution, for now i am on hostgator, do you know any search engine alternative that may work in shared hosting.

Comment: @chris i have got the godaddy hosting is it good ?

Comment: godaddy outside of domain registration, is just horrible. for anything. they lock there systems down tight. almost everytime I do client work for a client with godaddy hosting of any kind I spend more time hacking to make things work than actually putting them together like I would anywhere else, you're gonna want a VPS thats like a dedicated box or a dedicated box. As you require a lot of root level access to get that script up and running